# How to set the profile picture validation in profile 2 module in drupal 7?

Tags: users, media

I am using [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module in my site. I want to hide the profile picture upload option at the time of registration. And after click on confirmation mail, i want to upload at least one profile picture means want to apply validation here. How to set the validation in profile picture that validation shows inside not at the time of registration. Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the template of your registration page and need not print the upload image field over there and when user will register your self print that field to the edit profile form page from where user can upload the picture ..

Thanks